# Confused about quotient ring

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, quotient-spaces

For $I$ an ideal of a commutative ring $R$, I'm confused about the object $R/I$. My understanding is that this is defined by $R/I := \{rI: r \in R\} = \{\{ri: i \in I\}: r \in R\}$.

However, by the definition of an ideal, if $i \in I$ and $r \in R$ then $ri \in I$. So surely for a given $r$ the set $\{ri: i \in I\}$ will just equal $I$? And hence $R/I=\{I\}$?

Clearly this is wrong somewhere but I can't see where.

Comment: An element of $R/I$ is a coset $r + I$. (The emphasis should be on the $+$ sign.)

Comment: @Randall oh, so it's defined by the addition operation rather than multiplication?

Comment: Yes.  ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: *So surely for a given $r$ the set $\{ri:i\in I\}$ will just equal $I$?* Surely it will often *not* be equal. Consider $r=0$ for example. But $\{ri:r\in R, i\in I\}=I$, of course.  This would be the union of the collection in your originally proposed definition of $R/I$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments already, the elements of the quotient are formed by *the group operation, not the monoid operation*.

Explicitly, the elements of the quotient are congruence classes of an equivalence relation defined by $r\sim s$ if $r-s\in I$.  In the end, we write the class of $r$ symbolically as "$r+I$".

The group axioms provide everything you need to make this $\sim$ an equivalence relation. Without inverses though, this definition doesn't work, so monoids are different.

That doesn't mean quotients of monoids don't exist, it's just that one can't get a natural one from the binary operation like we did above, because we can't use inverses.

It still makes perfect sense to ask what partitions of a monoid are compatible with the binary operation: these are called [congruences of the monoid](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Congruence_on_an_algebra#On_a_monoid).  I have not seen this applied in ring theory.

If it helps, then, you can just think of the underlying additive group of $R/I$ as exactly the same group abelian group you would get if you just thought of $R$ and $I$ as abelian groups. The kicker is just that there is *also* a well-defined monoid operation that makes $R/I$ a ring, if $I$ is a two-sided ideal.